# Integration testing with MyBatis, H2 and Oracle procedures

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, h2, mybatis

I have a stored Oracle procedure that I call like so:

```
CALL MY_PROC(
        p_arg    =>   #{arg,     jdbcType=INTEGER,  mode=IN},
        p_var    =>   #{var,     jdbcType=VARCHAR,  mode=IN},
        p_date   =>   #{date,    jdbcType=DATE,     mode=IN}
    )
```

and I have it written using `MyBatis` like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE mapper
        PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN"
        "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">
<mapper namespace="com.example.MyMapper">
    <update id="callMyProc" statementType="CALLABLE">
        CALL MY_PROC(
            p_arg    => #{arg,    jdbcType=INTEGER,  mode=IN},
            p_var    => #{var,    jdbcType=VARCHAR,  mode=IN},
            p_date   => #{date,   jdbcType=DATE,     mode=IN}
        )
    </update>
</mapper>
```

The procedure itself does some `FOR UPDATE` as I have to lock on rows before updating them. The code does its job but I now I wanted to write some integration tests for which I am using H2 as database. I know that in such cases I am supposed to write user-defined function to handle such occasions. I was pretty sure that writing one such as (the sql query is simplified for the sake of the question):

```
CREATE ALIAS IF NOT EXISTS MY_PROC AS $$
import java.net.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
@CODE
void callMyProc(Connection conn, Integer p_arg, String p_var, LocalDateTime p_date) throws Exception {
    String sqlStatement = String.format("UPDATE mytable SET myvar = '%s', mydate = '%t' WHERE myarg = %d", p_var, p_date, p_arg);
    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sqlStatement);
    ps.execute();
}
$$;
```

would do the trick but unfortunately I am getting syntax errors due to MyBatis formatting:

```
### The error may exist in com.example/MyMapper.xml
### The error may involve com.example.MyMapper.callMyProc
### The error occurred while executing an update
### SQL: CALL MY_PROC(                 p_arg       => ?, p_var => ?, p_date => ?  )
### Cause: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Błąd składniowy w wyrażeniu SQL "CALL MY_PROC(
                P_ARG[*]       => ?,
                P_VAR[*]       => ?,
                P_DATE[*]       => ?
            )"
Syntax error in SQL statement "CALL MY_PROC(
                P_ARG[*]       => ?,
                P_VAR[*]       => ?,
                P_DATE[*]       => ?
CALL MY_PROC(
                p_arg       => ?,
                p_var[*]       => ?,
                p_date[*]       => ?
            ) [42000-200]
```

My question is, how could should I write my H2 alias for the procedure so that both MyBatis and H2 would be satisfied?

Comment: H2 does not seem to support the syntax `p_x => ?` even with `MODE=Oracle`. Try changing the parameter references from `p_x => #{y}` to just `#{y}`.

Answer (score 0):

As user ave suggested it turned out that it is in fact sufficient to get rid of Oracles syntax and just have the MyBatis mapper written like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE mapper
        PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN"
        "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">
<mapper namespace="com.example.MyMapper">
    <update id="callMyProc" statementType="CALLABLE">
        CALL MY_PROC(
            #{arg,    jdbcType=INTEGER,  mode=IN},
            #{var,    jdbcType=VARCHAR,  mode=IN},
            #{date,   jdbcType=TIMESTAMP,     mode=IN}
        )
    </update>
</mapper>
```

I had to also change the `date` type to `TIMESTAMP` and an alias should look like this:

```
CREATE ALIAS IF NOT EXISTS MY_PROC AS $$
import java.net.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.util.Date;
@CODE
void callMyProc(Connection conn, Integer p_arg, String p_var, Date p_date) throws Exception {
    String sqlStatement = String.format("UPDATE mytable SET myvar = '%s', mydate = PARSEDATETIME('%s','yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') WHERE myarg = %d", p_var, p_date.toString(), p_arg);
    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sqlStatement);
    ps.execute();
}
$$;
```

to match `LocalDateTime` type of Java (at this point mapping from `LocalDateTime` to `java.util.Date` is done automatically). The only downside of have it written that way is that you have to pay attention to the order of the arguments while calling the stored procedure.